# How to write for auto update

Tags: html, css

(I'm new to all this... instead of closing my question, it would help if I could have an idea of what needs to be done) (please excuse if I'm not asking the proper question for what I'm trying to achieve, new to code)

New to coding: web development Learning HTML, CSS and then JS.

I see websites where data is automatically updated. How is this achieved?

I would like to create a website that will display economic data but not have to manually input the data. How would I incorporate code to automatically do this for me?
Would I use a websites API?

Example of the type of information I would like to display on my own website: https://www.marketwatch.com/economy-politics/calendar

Comment: There are a variety of things you can do, and overall what you're asking is too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  If you want to get data from your own database, you can do that with server-side code in a language of your choice.  To get data from a 3rd party API, some allow direct access from JavaSript/AJAX and some do not, the latter would also require server-side code on your part.  To fetch data from your server without refreshing the page, you'd use JavaScript/AJAX to make requests to your server-side code.

Comment: Thank you appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatically updated data on a website can be achieved by using an API call. You make a request to an API that has the data and then render the data on your HTML page.

The process requires a good understanding of modern JS concepts.

Search for an API that offers the service you need and read the documentation to understand how to use it.

Let me know if there' anything else.